# What's the best way to debug Vapor 4?

Tags: macos, vapor

Environment: Vapor 4.77+
MacOS: 13.4.1

**Goal:** To step thru the vapor code in real time and inspect elements as I normally do with a regular iOS/MacOS app via Xcode.

Here's a snippet example of what I want to look at:

```swift
struct FormData: Content {
    let name: String
    let image: File
}    

struct MultiPartController: RouteCollection {
    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {
        let multiPartRoute = routes.grouped("MultiPart")
        multiPartRoute.on(.POST, body: .collect(maxSize: "10mb"), use: uploadMultiParts)
    }

    func uploadMultiParts(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<String> {
        do {
            let form = try req.content.decode(FormData.self)

            let name = form.name
            let imageFile = form.image

            // Get image data and filename
            let imageData = imageFile.data
            let filename = imageFile.filename
            // ...
```

Here's the Vapor debugger run, attempting to interface with it:

```
/Users/username/workarea/vapor/imageserverclient/imageuploadvapor> swift run --debugger
Building for debugging...
Build complete! (0.37s)
(lldb) target create ".build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/App"
Current executable set to '/Users/username/workarea/vapor/imageserverclient/imageuploadvapor/.build/arm64-apple-macosx/debug/App' (arm64).
(lldb) step
error: Command requires a current process.
```

Do I have to launch a parallel process and debug per process id?

What's the typical way of stepping thru the code in real time, inspecting variables, etc. as is done via Xcode's debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exact same process - run the app in Xcode and put breakpoints on the lines you want etc. You can also run in VSCode with the Swift extension to get the same experience.

(If you want to debug from the command line you should launch the app via LLDB)

Comment: Odd, I could have sworn the breaks didn't work when I last tried.   Working now.